# Titanium HTTPClient doesn't send POST params on android

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I try the following request in Titanium

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open("POST", "http://www.example.com");
var params = {
    username = "username",
    password = "password"
};
xhr.send(params);
```

The problem is that it works in iPhone Simulator, but not on the android emulator/device
The request comes through to the server, but if I print the params in my php page, they are both empty.

Comment: Same problem for me, I am using put method instead but the server doens't print anything... Did you find the solution? It works for me in iPhone as well...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `username: 'username'`, not `username = 'username'`?

Answer (score 0):

Some webservers need the content type set or they don't pull out the parameters.  Have you tried sniffing the header and contents of the Android traffic through proxy server?

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.open("POST", "http://www.example.com");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
var params = {
    username = "username",
    password = "password"
};
xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me I'm using Lift. Maybe your server doesn't handle it well.